# Ansible error: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching "

Tags: ansible, coreos

I am trying to use Ansible with several CoreOS virtual machines. I've installed ActivePython, and the binaries are recognized by the system. When I try to use a builtin Ansible module (ping) to test, it throws the following error:

```
deploy@kube-bh:~$ ansible dhcp-coreos155 -m ping
dhcp-coreos155 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to dhcp-coreos155 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `\"'\r\n/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I run an Ansible command with `-m raw`, it succeeds:

```
deploy@kube-bh:~$ ansible dhcp-coreos155 -m raw -a 'uptime'
dhcp-coreos155 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
 20:02:21 up 1 day, 22:11,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Shared connection to dhcp-coreos155 closed.
```

I used the `-vvvv` flag on the failing command to see the connection state, and it appears SSH is connecting properly to the CoreOS node. I do glean a bit more information, but why the error is occurring is not clear.

```
<dhcp-coreos155> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deploy
<dhcp-coreos155> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=deploy -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/deploy/.ansible/cp/6852b73873 -tt dhcp-coreos155 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-fisdfsesqopuqybnmnfhfdijsvkmxvoh; /home/deploy/bin/python" /home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510602904.61-255211842882017/ping.py; rm -rf "/home/deploy/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510602904.61-255211842882017/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<dhcp-coreos155> (1, '/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"\'\r\n/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file\r\n', 'Shared connection to dhcp-coreos155 closed.\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you have messed with Python executable definition somewhere (you don't show the config, it's likely the Ansible inventory or `ansible.cfg`) -- there is an unbalanced quotation mark in the command Ansible executes:

```
 /home/deploy/bin/python"
```

Shell opens a quote, but before it finds matching closing quotation mark, the whole command ends, so  it throws an unexpected EOF-found exception.

---

`raw` module doesn't call Python, so there is no error.